# Chrome plugin running a function but not found

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want my plugin to inject so that when i click on the button, it runs a function in the current tab.  However, it's giving me a function not found error.. is there some way to do this?

This is my popup.html:

```
<script>
    function start() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript( null,
            { code: "func_in_body()",
            allFrames: true } 
        );
    }

    start();
</script>
```

and even though the function is in the page, it gives me an error

The error is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: func_in_body is not defined
(anonymous function)
```

though one of the buttons' onclick uses it.  I'm not sure if there's a scope issue or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a popup to execute a function or a script on the current tab. What I did is, I made a background page with:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var iconName = "icon.png";
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:iconName});


  function onClicked(){
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"});
  }



  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(onClicked);
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

the background page has to be defined in the manifest.json

```
...
"background_page": "background.html",
...
```

and the last thing just create the content_script.js (or whatever you called it) and enter your code there.

**Edit:**
Don't forget to add the permissions that your script can be executed on every site

```
...
"permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
...
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript you inject into tabs is executed in a isolated environment and does not have access to the pages JavaScript. You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment).

Comment: Is there a canon way to handle this without all the message passing?